# Zedgraph : horizontal bar stack with date axis

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I try to create a horizontal bar stack with ZedGraph in C#.
I have already achieved [this](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/689293Sanstitre.png).
This image is supposed to be a kind of calendar, one bar size 30 minutes, red bars means busy, green ones means free time.

But, as you can see, the X values (Time) are not good at all. The image represents only one day (my `XDate()` data goes from 20/12/2011 0h0m0s to 21/12/2011 0h0m0s) but if I zoom I have year 9999..

Here is my code. I can't find my error(s).

Thanks for you help.

```cs
gPane.BarSettings.Type = BarType.Stack;
gPane.BarSettings.Base = BarBase.Y;
gPane.BarSettings.ClusterScaleWidth = 1; // Widen bars

gPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time (sec)";
gPane.XAxis.Scale.FontSpec.Angle = 65f;
gPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm";
gPane.XAxis.Scale.BaseTic = dataBar[0].X;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = dataBar[0].X;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = dataBar[dataBar.Count - 1].X;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Day;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit = DateUnit.Day;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = 1;
gPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 2;

foreach (PointPair pp in dataBar)
{
    //pp.X = XDate date (double)
    //pp.Y = 0 (free) ou 1 (busy)

    Color col = Color.Green;
    if (pp.Y == 1)
        col = Color.Red;

    gPane.AddBar("", /* I don't need it */
                new double[] { pp.X }, /* the current XDate date*/
                new double[] { 30 /* width of bar */ },
                col);
}

gPane.AxisChange();
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try control your XDate obj while adding a bar?
try xDate.AddDays(1) to control your xAxis value.